# How to send emails without speed limit?

Tags: limit, jakarta-mail

I got some errors about sending mails too quick in 15 minutes when sending mails.
It seems there is a speed limit of sending mails.
But how many mails can be sent in 15 minutes?
Is this a standard or private rule based on vendor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on both your mail service provider, and also the target system. For example gmail will let you send 500/1000 (or more) emails per day, per account depending on your agreement with them.

Comment: how to accept your answer?there is no a 'accept' button to click.